# Seleiumn With Gcloud

Tags: php, selenium

We have Google Cloud Server and set up Selenium Grid on it. Selenium Grid hub is up and running.

But when I want to reach ip::4444/grid/console/ from my PC browser, I cannot 
reach it.

I also cannot test from my PC; I do everything as Node in My PC.

When I go to the Google cloud Server (The Test Inteface) and enter Start Test, the test does not start. I get this message: " Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities "

I use PHP (Facebook Webdriver).

Comment: AFAIK, to set up a grid, both the instances should be in the same network or they would need public IP. Are you sure you fulfilling these criteria?

Comment: No Not In Same Network , When Setup seleium server on webserver They give Me internal Ip Of My Webserver To Use In Node But not work @4M01

Comment: Did you open the 4444 port in the network security group?

Comment: @TarunLalwani How Can I Open It ? The Problem I Cannot Reach The Internal Ip

Comment: How do you connect to the machine for SSH?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I Connect Via SSh As admin And The Seleium Grid Work And Running But I Can not Access It From My Pc As Node My Pc Cannot Reach The http://ip/grid/register And I Cannot Reach  http://ip/grid/console From My Web Browser

Comment: To understand better i need to see the complete process you are using, basically your infrastructure details is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two level of firewalls, one is Gcloud. Next is your machine

Gcloud firewall needs to allow `4444`. Then you need to check firewall of machine using `iptables -S`

If you see the port is not allowed, you can use below iptables statement to add it

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 4444 -j ACCEPT
```